# How to show certain column of a record using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a list like this:

```
5678:robert dylan   :d.g.m. :marketing  :04/19/43 85000
```

I want to show only the name and designation of the person. I want to use `sed` for that. How should I do that?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `awk` or `cut` etc? Are you specifically looking for a `sed` solution?

Comment: Yes just sed is allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**:

```
echo "5678:robert dylan :d.g.m. :marketing :04/19/43 85000" | 
sed 's/:/\n/g' | sed '1d;3d;$d'| sed 'N;s/\n/ - /'
```

yields

```
robert dylan - marketing
```

*Explanation:*

Works by splitting the line into several lines based on `:`, deleting the first, third and last lines, and then joining them up again.

**NOTE**: In the last expression, *you can specify what separates the name from the designation* by putting something else between the final set of `/  /` in `'N;s/\n/  /'`

---

*Previous AWK solution*:

Not `sed`, but `awk` is quite a natural tool for this if it is acceptable:

```
$ echo "5678:robert dylan :d.g.m. :marketing :04/19/43 85000" | awk -F":" '{print $2, $4}'
```

yields

```
robert dylan  marketing
```

Alternatively, if your data was stored in a file named `data.txt`:

```
awk -F":" '{print $2, $4}' data.txt
```

would produce the same output.

[awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) is really well suited for these sort of tasks.

*Explanation*:

```
awk -F":" '{print $2, $4}'
```

`-F` sets the field separator to `:`, `print $2, $4` print resulting fields 2 and 4 respectively. You can use `printf` to format the output as specific as you need.

Comment: @sweet I added a `sed` solution with explanation .. just FYI

Comment: @sweet You motivated me to look more into `sed`, I was able to simplify the solution more. This is just for your future reference in case you need something similar and simple.

Answer (score 7):

Just thought I'd drop in the solution using `cut`

```
 cut -d ":" -f 2,4
```

produces:

```
 robert dylan :marketing
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
echo "5678:robert dylan :d.g.m. :marketing :04/19/43 85000" |
sed 's/[^:]*:\([^:]*:\)[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1\2/'
robert dylan :marketing
```

Explanation:

The left hand side (LHS) of the substitute command says:

- `[^:]*:` match zero or more non `:`'s followed by a `:` - this matches `5678:`
- `\([^:]*:\)` as above but will be remembered as a back reference `\1` - matches `robert dylan :`
- `[^:]*:` as above but no back reference - matches `d.g.m. :`
- `\([^:]*\)` as above (excepting the `:` but will be remembered as a back reference `\2` - matches `marketing`
- `:.*` a `:` followed by everything else - matches `:04/19/43 85000`

The right hand side of the substitute command says:

- `\1\2` replace the left hand side by the first and second back references.

Comment: very nice explanation .. though it makes me feel a bit dizzy :) Clearly I have much to learn about `sed`, back references seem very useful .. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Lavon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376656/438457), but adapted to multiple records

```
sed -n 's/:/\n/pg' file | sed -n '2~5h;4~5{H;g;s/\n/|/g;p}'
```

will produce

```
robert dylan |marketing 
penny farthing |accident & emergency 
...
```

For input file

```
5678:robert dylan :d.g.m. :marketing :04/19/43 85000
8076:penny farthing :d.g.m. :accident & emergency :04/19/43 85000
...
```

First replace `:` with `\n` new-line to get 5 lines per record; then 
for each set of 5 lines, copy the 2nd and append the 4th to the holding space, transfer to the pattern space, replace `\n` with a separator (in this case `|`) and print. (If you don't care about column order `{H;g;...` can be shortened to `{G;...`.)